# One TV gets signal while another does not..same cable

Tags: tv-antenna

I have a rooftop antenna. It comes in, goes to an amplified splitter and off to the 2 TVs... when I first set it up, I was delighted because all the stations came in perfectly.  Over the next few months, I lost everything under 18 (splotchy or nonexistent)... I am testing out a small TV I found and plugged it in to the wire that was attached to one of the TVs and all channels come in pristine...same wire. Why? This tv is tiny so I don’t want it, I like my big TVs but want my channels as well. What is wrong? (P.S. I even tried rescanning and it makes no difference)

Comment: Not all tuners inside televisions are created equal. Some tuners are able to get stations well and some tuners not at all depends on the quality of the components inside and the quality of the manufacturing.

Comment: Make sure your TV is set for "antenna".  It might have been inadvertently  switched to a different setting.  Make sure the connections are tight.

Comment: Did you try re-scanning your big TV(s)?  Some of the stations in your area have been changing their broadcast frequency and so you may need to update your channels stored in your TV.

Comment: There needs to be a splitter. If the impedance is not matched this sounds normal to me.

Comment: There is a splitter mentioned.

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with one or both your big TVs.